# A positive number from 1 to 2^31 -1 in regex

Tags: regex, validation

I got the following regex that almost does the work but does not exclude zero ...How to do that?

```
^(\d|\d{1,9}|1\d{1,9}|20\d{8}|213\d{7}|2146\d{6}|21473\d{5}|214747\d{4}|2147482\d{3}|21474835\d{2}|214748364[0-7])$
```

Also can anybody explain a bit how this works?

Comment: If you want to exclude zero, change the first two alternatives from `\d|\d{1,9}` to `[1-9]\d{0,8}|1\d{9}`.  That will exclude any number that *starts* with `0`, not just zero.  If you want to permit leading zeroes, you can match them explicitly: `^0*(` etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regular expressions are *not* the right tool for this job. A much better solution is to extract the integer from your string (you can use a regex for this, just `\d+`), then convert that to an integer, then check the integer against your desired range.

An important corollary is to never blindly use a regular expression (or any code, really) that you don't understand yourself. What would you do if you used the regular expression above, then a requirement came in to modify the acceptable range?

Comment: +1 So true! Unless this is homework (in which case the code would never be used), regular expressions are definitely not the right tool.

Comment: You are right. Now I am using asp:RangeValidator for this. :)

Answer (score 4):

As Greg said, regexes are not the right tool for the job here. But if you insist on knowing how the regex you pasted works:

The most important thing to remember is that `2**31 - 1 = 2147483647` (a number with 10 digits). In essence, the regex says:

- The number can have 1-9 digits, OR
- It can be 1 with any 9 digits after it, OR
- 20 with any 8 digits after it, OR
- 213 with any 7 digits after it, OR
- ... I'm sure you see where it's going

It restricts the numbers to the range of being below 2147483647.

P.S. given such a number as a string `s`, in Python, you can just pose this condition:

```
1 <= int(s) <= 2**31 - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, your regex *doesn't* work (besides allowing 0): it incorrectly excludes numbers like 2100000000, 2147483639, and most of the numbers between those two.  The solution is to replace most of the `nnnn` prefixes with `nnn[0-n]` (along with other fixes), but the *real* solution is to not use regular expressions.