# jQuery's maskedinput

Tags: jquery, input

I want to limit an html input field to an input like

Name 1 & Name 2,

so that the user can only type in two names in the format

e.g. "Steven & Peter" or "Alex & Jennifer".

I tried it with jQuery "maskedinput" and

$('.picName').mask('aaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaa');

but here the user has to input EXACTLY 8 characters per name, but I want it to set to MAX. 8 characters per name. Does anybody know if that's possible with maskedinput?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can define your own regex inputs:
from: http://digitalbush.com/2008/12/08/masked-input-plugin-12/

> You should now add custom mask definitions by
>   "$.mask.definitions[char]=regex;"

So, with some regex you can do somthing like this:
from: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

> You could use \b[1-9][0-9]{3}\b to match a number between 1000 and
>   9999. \b[1-9][0-9]{2,4}\b matches a number between 100 and 99999. Notice the use of the word boundaries.

Comment: The "$." part is extending the jQuery object; you'd be adding your own custom mask by doing $.mask.definitions['myMask']= regex. The regex part is where you would build a custom regular expression to catch what you want. Basically, any number up to 8 digits. I did a little poking around and you might need to implement something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926683/a-positive-number-from-1-to-231-1-in-regex or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.picName').mask('aaaaaaaa & aaaa?aaaa');
```

Everything behind the question mark will be optional.

**Source:** Last example on the plugin page: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: But that would mean I had to input a name with 8 characters and a name with at least 4. "Nick & Jon" would be impossible then?